# Can I Cast a Class A to Its Interface B? in JAVA

Tags: java

if Class A implements a interface B, can I CAST A to B and still get all functions working properly?

my current problem is that a function use type B as its argument, can I cast A to B and pass it to the function.

Comment: What happened when you didn't cast at all and used the value of static type `A` as an argument?

Comment: then Eclipse shows error. it says it is not applicable for the arguments

Comment: Then you're doing it wrong for reasons other than those you describe in your question.